# Can I create a (for-profit) cooperative in Ethereum?

Tags: dao

I am interested in cooperatives in the physical world, and learning about DAO provides interesting possibilities for the Cooperative world. So far I have see no attempt to create a cooperative in Ethereum. I don't even know if its possible. But judging by descriptions of the DAO (and the fact that you can create a [non-business democratic organisation](https://www.ethereum.org/dao#the-blockchain-congress)), I imagine it might be possible to set up a cooperative in Ethereum. Is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can setup a cooperative on the Ethereum blockchain by writing a [smart contract](https://www.ethereum.org/greeter).

You are not clear on exactly what you want to achieve, but in principle you can write a contract (in [Solidity](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) which allows payments to be received, and then distributed to cooperative participants dependent on user defined rules.

You should read more about [The DAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_DAO_(organization)). The concept was/is an incredible idea. The lesson is that if you want to write a smart contract dealing with significant amounts of money then you need to make sure it does what you expect it to, and is not vulnerable to hacking.